# Reallocating a matrix' row count to a number larger than the initial value

Tags: c, matrix, realloc

I have a program to create a matrix with initial values and then changing the matrix to given values. But when I try to change the row count to a number equal to or larger than the initial value, the program crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
void fill(int row, int column, int **arr){
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
        *(*(arr + i)+j) = k;
           k++;}}}

void print(int row, int column, int **arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
           printf("%d\t", *(*(arr +i ) + j));}
       printf("\n");}}

int **create(int row, int column){
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
       *(arr + i) = (int *)malloc(column * sizeof(int));}
    return arr;}

int** modify(int oldRowCount, int row, int column, int **arr){
     arr =(int **) realloc(arr,(unsigned long) row * sizeof (int **));

     for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
         *(arr + i) =(int *) realloc(*(arr+i),(unsigned long) column * sizeof (int));

     if(oldRowCount <= row){
         for (int i = oldRowCount; i < row; i++)
             *(arr + i) = (int *)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
     }
    else{
         for(int i = row + 1; i <= oldRowCount; i++)
             free(*(arr + i));
     }
     return arr;}

int main()
{
    int row = 4;
    int column = 4;
    int oldRowCount=row;

    int **arr = create(row,column);
    fill(row, column, arr);
    print(row, column, arr);

    while(1){
    oldRowCount = row;
    scanf("%d",&row);
    scanf("%d",&column);
    arr = modify(oldRowCount, row, column, arr);
    fill(row, column, arr);
    print(row, column, arr);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even after fixing that, If `row` changes by increase, then your enumeration to reallocate existing rows will be using `arr[i]` slots with no actual rows allocated prior, yet still passing their values down to `realloc`.  And if it changes on the *decrease*, you'll be leaking memory from orphaned rows. And that, kids, is why dynamic arrays are managed in *structures* that include the current size allocation limits.

Comment: `arr =(int **) realloc(arr,(unsigned long) row * sizeof (int **));`. `arr` is local to the function. What you have done is to free the original `arr` and then allocate a new block that is lost when the function exits. That is, after that code in `modify`, the subsequent `fill` call gets passed an `arr` that has been freed.

Comment: I don't understand why arr is a local variable even when I passed the address of it @kaylum

Comment: `modify(row, column, arr);` That does not pass the address of `arr` to the function. The address of `arr` is `&arr`. In C all function args are passed by value.

Comment: *"even when I passed the address"* - you're not passing the address *of* the pointer; you're passing the address **in** the pointer (i.e. it's value). More succinctly, if `p` is a pointer-type arg, then `p = ` changes nothing on the caller side; `*p = ...` does. You can avoid being [a 3-star programmer](https://www.cliki.net/Three%20Comma%20Programmer) by using the otherwise-unused result of `modify` as you have in your updated code. I caution you to read my first comment. It exposes a major design flaw and you need to re-evaluate how you plan to account for that problem.

Comment: okay I thought I figured pointers out but I guess  I didn't... @WhozCraig I  understand your point, but I'm not sure if I can implement what you suggested with my current knowledge but I'll try, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its going on because realloc() try realloc empty memory. For example if new rows count = 6, then when i = 4, realloc try realloc pointer to nowhere. Also arr should be accepted by reference in this case.

```
void modify(int row, int column, int oldRowCount, int** &arr) {
arr = (int **)realloc(arr, row * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < oldRowCount; i++) {
    *(arr + i) = (int *)realloc(*(arr + i), column * sizeof(int));
}

for (int i = oldRowCount; i < row; i++) {
    *(arr + i) = (int *)malloc(column * sizeof(int));
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        *(*(arr + i) + j) = 0;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just for kicks (and my upvote) add the code to properly *free* rows in the contraction case (i.e. when `row` is *smaller* than `oldRowCount`). And btw, C has no reference-types so `int** &arr` isn't valid C anyway.